# how can i use named routes and their child routes in nuxt 3?

Tags: routes, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, vue-router4

i have this file structure

```
pages/
--posts/
----[id].vue
----index.vue
--about.vue
--index.vue
```

and this navbar

```html
<NuxtLink to="/">home</NuxtLink>
<NuxtLink to="/posts">posts</NuxtLink>
<NuxtLink to="/about">about</NuxtLink>
```

im trying to take parameter with an input in `/posts/index.vue` page and go to `/posts/:id` page. i used this in `/posts/index.vue`

```html
<script setup>
const id = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="id"><br>
  <NuxtLink :to="`posts/${id}`">go</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

its works but not in `/posts` page, I can only access it directly via the url. (like `/posts/3`) but I can't redirect with NuxtLink because when i try to go to post page i get `500 Missing required param "id"` error. i dont know why, is this route not correct ?

i changed NuxtLink `:to` property to template literals

```html
<NuxtLink :to="`posts/${id}`">go</NuxtLink>
```

its work as well, i can access the `/posts` page and can route to `id` but this time when I use `useActiveClass` or `useExactActiveClass,` (color: green) it is applied to both the `/posts` link in the navbar and the `go` link on the posts page.

i dont understand how named routes work. i dont know why first NuxtLink getting error. is this named route not correct ?

Comment: What do you have inside `posts/index.vue`?

Comment: a ref for id, an v-modeled input and a NuxtLink. i updated `posts/index.vue` content

Comment: Just to confirm, these codes you provided are currently present on your `/posts/index.vue` page right? The usage of your `NuxtLink` is correct. If you can put your codes in stackblitz, maybe we can investigate deeper.  https://stackblitz.com

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough, i have a layout too. here are [codes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-qmnnki)

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt uses `vue-router` under the hood, that means `posts/index.vue` would need its own `<NuxtPage>` in the template in order to display child pages such as (`[id].vue`).

you will have to move your current content in `posts/index.vue` to another file like `latest.vue` or `blog.vue` for example or you can actually display a post above current code that lists posts by putting  above your listing loop.

Comment: but this time using sub-routes doesn't make sense